# How to use stored attribute to select dropdown value

Tags: javascript, xpath, selenium-ide

Hi I'm fairly new in doing automation and I'm starting with Selenium IDE,
What I wanted was to to save the configuration of the User and when the user creates a new account, the dropdown value that will be selected will be based on the user's configuration.

So what I did is save the attribute by using xpath as locator

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>xpath=//div['divname']/div[2]/div[10]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]@'spanname'</td>
    <td>Callvariable</td>
</tr>
```

This is my code when calling it and trying to put it in the dropdown
    
        select
        id=dropdown
        ${Callvariable}

When I try to call it, it gives me an error message:

> [error] Option with label '${Callvariable}' not found

Answer (score 0):

This error means your variable is unset.

I think it's the single quotes around spanname. You shouldn't be using them assuming the attribute is just spanname.

If this doesn't fix it please attach the html element source code for us to see.